# SOAP tester: Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class

Tags: java, soap, netbeans, xsd

When I open the tester for my SOAP webservice it shows the following error on the webpage:

```
Exceptions details : null

com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.AbortException at 
com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.JAXBModelBuilder.bind(JAXBModelBuilder.java:144) at 
com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.buildJAXBModel(WSDLModeler.java:2244) at 
com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.internalBuildModel(WSDLModeler.java:191) at 
com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.buildModel(WSDLModeler.java:137) at 
com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.buildWsdlModel(WsimportTool.java:381) at 
com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.run(WsimportTool.java:198) at 
com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.run(WsimportTool.java:179) at 
com.sun.tools.ws.util.WSToolsObjectFactoryImpl.wsimport(WSToolsObjectFactoryImpl.java:60) at 
com.sun.tools.ws.spi.WSToolsObjectFactory.wsimport(WSToolsObjectFactory.java:88) at 
org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.wsImport(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:626) at 
org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.initializePort(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:522) at 
org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.doGet(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:169) at 
org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.invoke(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:104) at 
org.glassfish.webservices.JAXWSServlet.doGet(JAXWSServlet.java:186) at .....
```

The GlassFish log has this:

```
INFO: [ERROR] Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.
INFO:   line 341 of http://localhost:8080/RegistratieProject/UpdateService?xsd=1
INFO: [ERROR] (Related to above error) This is the other declaration.   
INFO:   line 334 of http://localhost:8080/RegistratieProject/UpdateService?xsd=1
```

Everything is generated. The xsd lines:

```
  <xs:complexType name="typeUpdate">
    <xs:sequence> <== LINE 334
      <xs:element name="action" type="xs:int"/>
      <xs:element name="tagCollection" type="tns:tags" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xs:element name="typeObject" type="tns:type" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="getLocationUpdates"> <== LINE 341
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="companyID" type="xs:long"/>
      <xs:element name="pw" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="from" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="deviceID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Can anyone explain what is going on and maybe how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this. Some property names had wrong names compared to their member. Was easy to check in all classes in NetBeans using insert code.

Comment: please explain because my matter is bit diff (i opened Netbeans6.1built webprojects in Netbeans8.1) but error/exception is same